# Upgraded to ColdFusion 9 getting strange cfif error

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I have a couple of places that have some code like this:

```
<cfinvoke component="#application.path#cfc/eval_faculty" method="getPresentations" returnvariable="presentations">
    <cfinvokeargument name="id" value="#eval_id#">
    <cfinvokeargument name="evalYear" value="#eval_semester#">
    <cfinvokeargument name="department" value="#general.dept#">
</cfinvoke>

<cfset prescheck = 0>
<cfloop query="presentations">
    <cfif local eq "" and regional eq "" and national eq "" and international eq "">
        <cfset prescheck = prescheck+1>
    </cfif>
</cfloop>
```

I get this error:

```
Complex object types cannot be converted to simple values.
```

None of these values in the cfif statement is a complex object.

This worked fine in ColdFusion 8. We just upgraded to ColdFusion 9...

The error occurs on the line with `<cfif local eq "" ... >`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ```
> <cfif local eq ""
> ```

It could be that `LOCAL` is now a system scope in CF9, like `FORM`, `URL`, etecetera. So CF complains when you try to perform a string comparison on it because it is a structure. If `LOCAL` represents a simple variable in your old code, try using a different variable name.

**Update**: From the comments, if `LOCAL` is the name of a column in your query, you could either use a sql alias to give it another name:

```
  SELECT Local AS LocalAlias FROM Table
```

... or use a fully qualified variable name:

```
   <cfif queryName.local ...>
```

Comment: What if I can't? Local is the name of the database table attribute. :(

Comment: Is this code being used inside a cffunction? You can always alias the column in your query `SELECT Local AS LocalAlias`. Then use the alias instead. Or you could try using a fully qualified name: ie `<cfif queryName.local ...>`.

Comment: Oh yeah. I'm so stupid today. I forgot you can do AS xxx ... but it will not be wise for me to change this as it is used in quite a few places. For now I'm doing query.local. I figured it would recognize local as being in said query scope when I specified the query in the <cfloop>.

Comment: Yeah, but a scope name will take precedence over query column names. You'd get the same result if you had a database column called "session", for instance.

Comment: @Al - Right, but fully qualifying the name ie `queryName.Local` should avoid that.